# Check whether these two groups are isomorphic using their Cayley tables

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-isomorphism

I have recently been introduced to the topic of Group Theory and I'm trying to do the practice questions. Was wondering if I got the idea of Isomorphism correct.

**Problem :**

Given two Cayley Tables :

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\circ & f_1 & f_2 & f_3 & f_4 \\ \hline
f_1   & f_1 & f_2 & f_3 & f_4 \\ \hline
f_2   & f_2 & f_1 & f_4 & f_3 \\ \hline
f_3   & f_3 & f_4 & f_1 & f_2 \\ \hline
f_4   & f_4 & f_3 & f_2 & f_1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
+  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
0  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ \hline
2  & 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
3  & 3 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\end{array}$

are the two groups Isomorphic? Justify your answer.

**Answer :**

The answer I have come to is that they are not Isomorphic because it is not possible to map the identity element ($f_1$) of the first group to the identity element (0) of the second group.

I understand there are many other requirements for groups to be considered isomorphic but I was wondering if this is a strong enough answer and justification?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks~

Comment: Note that in the diagonal of the first Cayley table there is the neutral element $f_1$ of this group, so all the elements of this group are of order 2, is this the fact in the second group?

Comment: @PeterMelech i've been trying to find definitions and examples of counting the order but im still confused, how do you go about counting it?

Comment: @PeterMelech I've refreshed my memory with a video on cyclic subgroups and remember some information with regards to counting the order. Just want to clarify, by using the Cayley table, I am able to count the order by looking at the diagonal of the table and counting the number of elements before it repeats am I correct?

Comment: Yes. As You can see from Your Cayley table You have $f_j^2=f_1$ for $j=1,..,4$ and thus all the elements generate a subgroup of order $2$:$\{f_j,f_1\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, you have no justification yet. You're basically saying that it's impossible because it's impossible. You need to find a convincing reason that $f_1$ can't be mapped to $0$.

Here's a hint for another direction you could take this: count the orders of the elements in each group.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I've been trying to search and definitions and examples of order of groups but I still do not understand how to go about counting the order though

Comment: I've refreshed my memory with a video on cyclic subgroups and remember some information with regards to counting the order. Just want to clarify, by using the Cayley table, I am able to count the order by looking at the diagonal of the table and counting the number of elements before it repeats am I correct?

Comment: @WeiXiongYeo You can find the order of an element $x$ by adding it to itself repeatedly until you get the identity. (By "adding" I mean applying the group operation.) In the Cayley table, if the identity $e$ appears on the diagonal, then the corresponding element $x$ has order $2$ (or $1$ in the case of the identity itself), since that means $x+x=e$. If the identity doesn't appear on the diagonal for some element, though, then you could carry out repeated operations:
$$1=1\\1+1=2\\1+1+1=3\\1+1+1+1=0$$
so the order of $1$ is $4$.

Comment: @WeiXiongYeo Note, however, that in this case it isn't necessary to find out the orders of all elements (although you could do so for the sake of practice). In the first group, all non-identity elements have order $2$, as you can see by the diagonal. But in the second, again looking at the diagonal, not all non-identity elements have order $2$. This is enough to show that the groups are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphisms preserve elements' order. In the former group (with identity $f_1$), all the nontrivial elements have order $2$. In the latter (with identity $0$), just $2$ has order $2$, whereas $1$ and $3$ have order $4$. Therefore, no one bijection between the two groups, sending nontrivial elements to nontrivial elements, can be order-preserving, so less an isomorphism.